# how to remove empty spaces of imageview without cropping them

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, instagram

> I'm trying to add a `ImageView` to my `CardView` but i don't know how
> to set image inside of `ImageView` that has a Full Width
> (`match_parent`) and a `wrap_content` height ! By default there would
> be some spaces in Imageview (bottom and top parts, depend on width and
> height of image) as you see below :

[image: how does instagram fill it's images without cropping them?]

> any way to remove these empty spaces without cropping images ?

**here is my layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardElevation="3dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ryan_gosling"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok the Problem is Solved.**
A really simple code :

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding scaletype to imageview. That would actually scale the image depending on what value to you give. [Here you can refer it.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: `scaletype` would crop the images, i found the solution myself : you can use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` that the images will scale exactly like instagram images do